# Insult for someone who "doesn't know anything"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, pejorative-language, offensive-language, epithet-requests

How do you call/insult someone who doesn't know anything (meaning not the simplest/basic or obvious things)?

Context: I need it in a dialog of the following form:

A: How does <very simple/obvious thing> work?
B: It works like <explanation>. <Insult>.

Searching various dictionaries I found already the following words:

- silly
- stupid
- idiot
- moron

But I have the feeling (as a non-native speaker) that they don't quite nail it and also I feel that the first two are quite weak insults. (Please correct me, if this impression is wrong.)

I would be happy if a single (short) word exists, but also longer words or phrases are welcome. Most important to me is that the insult/swear word is *authentic* (a native speaker would actually use it). And: the stronger the insult the better (for my specific project).

EDIT:

(OMG! I didn't imagine this topic would get so much attention!)

As some requested more context, I will try to summarize without revealing to much content here.

I'm writing a comic strip where there will appear two *digital assistants*. Both are assumed to be able answer a specific question, but one fails, leading to the other one insulting it.

So it's basically about missing knowledge/information.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Where are your characters specifically based? Insults, particularly strong ones, can be very locale dependent. "Bampot", "Eejit" and "Numpty" are great Scottish ones, but they might not be widely understood.

Comment: It should be globally understandable so assume (basic) American or British English.

Comment: Sarcasm is your friend, Einstein.

Comment: There's only one right answer and it is "Jon Snow".

Comment: Take a look at https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/746272130992644096 for insipration

Comment: @Arvindh Mani: Violates the understandability criterion.  I have absolutely no idea why "Jon Snow" would be considered an insult.

Comment: Actually, stupid, idiot and moron all fit your dialog just fine, and native speakers (at least US native speakers) would definitely use them in that context.  They do refer to a lack of mental ability rather than a lack of knowledge, but that probably make the insult even stronger.

Comment: Why do people insult intelligence when lack of knowledge is exhibited?

Comment: It would be helpful if the OP explained why he is looking for a stinging insult.  That is, what is the context?  Does this person habitually ask stupid questions, and if so, is it because of stupidity or laziness or dyslexia or lack of interest in a particular subject?  I feel uncomfortable with this question.

Comment: @jamesqf I don't think that was a serious suggestion. It's a reference to a specific line in Game of Thrones.

Comment: I VTC'd on the basis of Unclear What You Are Asking, because of the lack of context.  Is this for a story or book?  Is the presumably stupid person really stupid, or maybe lazy, or perpetually walking around in a dream, or dyslexic, or, say, extremely mechanically inept while being a genius in some abstruse theoretical field?  Is this for an "insult contest" that is being done in fun?

Comment: @John Montgomery: That's my point.  The intended insult would only be perceptable by those who are followers of that TV show.  (Or whatever it is: I'm not exactly sure.  About all I know of it comes from skimming the StackExchange Hot Questions.)

Comment: @jamesqf Which is why I don't think it was a serious suggestion.

Comment: As you're seeing from the answers, this is extremely broad.  The English language has a huge number of insults based on stupidity or ignorance.

Comment: "muppet",  or "mumpsimus" (a person who obstinately adheres to old ideas in spite of evidence that they are wrong or unreasonable)

Comment: Since you say its a comic strip, maybe have it relate to something IT related that's incompetent. Like internet explorer, or a bad search engine, or something outdated.

Answer (score 30):

It is not the short word you are looking for, but [ignoramus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ignoramus) means “a stupid or ignorant person.” It’s a bit old-fashioned sounding and underused.

Comment: I actually *have* used this as an insult. Even ignoramuses get that it is an insult.

Answer (score 17):

I'm partial to [dipshit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dipshit), which is a common slang word.

> a stupid or incompetent person

An example of this:

A) Ugh, I don't know why I have such a bad headache.

B) That's because you drank so much last night that you passed out, dipshit.

Comment: But I think that's not quite the meaning the OP is looking for.  Otherwise quite intelligent people - especially college students - can be prone to drinking too much and doing stupid things before passing out.

Comment: @jamesqf I was just using that example as someone asking a stupid question, like "Why do I have a headache?". Could also be used for many things like, "A: Ugh, I cant get this item OPEN! -- B: Why dont you try tearing it where it says 'rip along the dotted line', dipshit."

Comment: I would not generally associate _dipshit_ with intelligence – it’s just more or less synonymous with _asshole_ to me.

Comment: Perhaps you've been using it wrong then? Bc going by the dictionary definition, it means a stupid person and that's how I've always used it too. "Why can't i microwave my leftovers?" "Because it's wrapped in foil. It'll catch on fire, dipshit"

Answer (score 13):

Fuckwit.

It's a colloquialism, possibly specific to the UK, but it's meaning would be unambiguous to native English speaker. Functionally equivalent to *fucking halfwit*, but with a brevity and rhythm that makes it appealing to the native ear.

You could also consider "dickwit", but the (usually amusing) plosive "d" sounds doesn't work so well with the fricative "w" sound.

Comment: Fuckwit is awesome, although very rude and largely British. Asshat is another good choice. I think that's an "Americanism" however.

Comment: As an American, "Fuckwit" is not unfamiliar to me

Answer (score 11):

> the stronger the insult the better

**"you ignorant f*ck"** is about as strong as they come. I can't think of a worse.

Don't say it to anyone who is bigger than you or is holding a weapon!

Definitely don't say it if you care about your reputation as someone of good standing.

Comment: I like the "ignorant" part, but would be glad if there was a more subtle term than f*** :)

Comment: 'ignorant fool' -If the person tried but failed because of glaring gaps in knowledge; 'f*ck' probably does not translate well in the US, as there is quite a gradient between the meanings in Europe vs USA

Comment: correction: do not say it to anyone having a weapon. Definitely do not insult anyone in the US, unless you are on very good terms with them and are sure  they will not shoot in response.

Comment: As an American, I can confirm that "ignorant f***" means exactly the same thing. If you're looking for something without profanity, but still slightly vulgar, I hear "twat" is usually a good substitute.

Answer (score 7):

The word [**imbecile**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/imbecile) is a good one. I think originally it's the name of a type of very severe intellectual disability, but nowadays it has become a word people use to insult someone who they think are incredibly stupid because they're showing the inability to understand even the simplest of things. Here's how the Cambridge Dictionary defines this word:

> person who behaves in an extremely stupid way

Example sentence:

> What **an imbecile** that boy is!

Your sentence:

> A: How exactly does it work?
>   B: It works like this, you **imbecile**!

Answer (score 6):

Since you've asked for a strong insult, ***[retard](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/retard#Noun)*** fits the bill.

> (offensive, vulgar) A stupid person, or one who is slow to learn.

It acquired this sense via the [euphemism treadmill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism#Evolution), having once been a neutral term to describe someone who would once have been called an *idiot* or *moron* in a clinical context, but is now considered more offensive than either of those.

Exercise caution, because it's a highly politically incorrect term. Even if you're writing character dialogue, it won't only be the addressed character that takes offence, but a significant part of the audience as well.

Comment: Would "retard" also fit when the person in question is not assumed to be stupid/dumb in general and might also not be a slow learner, but just simply lacks **a lot of** information?

Comment: Like any colloquial insult, there aren't any hard rules on using it (other than "don't use it if you don't want to offend someone"). A lot of the time it's used to insult stupid behaviour, or a glaring gap in knowledge, rather than a person's inherent stupidity.

Comment: "Retard" is now considered not PC (politically correct) because it insults those who are mentally retarded as a medical condition. So much so that "mentally retarded" is now falling out of use. Strong insults don't tend to be very PC, but it's still worth mentioning.

Comment: @DuncanC What's interesting to me is that ['idiot', 'moron', 'imbecile', and 'cretin'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiot) have similar origins but don't carry this kind of baggage.

Comment: And in British English, f*cktard goes with f*ckwit

Answer (score 5):

> How do you call/insult someone who doesn't know anything (meaning not the simplest/basic or obvious things)?

There are various techniques one might employ for insults.

Something short and simple, not too offensive sounding at first, but quite insulting:

- [dimwit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dimwit) noun
  dim·​wit | \ ˈdim-ˌwit
  : a stupid or mentally slow person

  That page contains a wonderful list of synonyms:

  > "airhead, birdbrain, blockhead, bonehead, bubblehead, chowderhead, chucklehead, clodpoll (or clodpole), clot [British], cluck, clunk, cretin, cuddy (or cuddie) [British dialect], deadhead, dim bulb [slang], dip, dodo, dolt, donkey, doofus [slang], dope, dork [slang], dullard, dum-dum, dumbbell, dumbhead, dummkopf, dummy, dunce, dunderhead, fathead, gander, golem, goof, goon, half-wit, hammerhead, hardhead, idiot, ignoramus, imbecile, jackass, know-nothing, knucklehead, lamebrain, loggerhead [chiefly dialect], loon, lump, lunkhead, meathead, mome [archaic], moron, mug [chiefly British], mutt, natural, nimrod [slang], nincompoop, ninny, ninnyhammer, nit [chiefly British], nitwit, noddy, noodle, numskull (or numbskull), oaf, pinhead, prat [British], ratbag [chiefly Australian], saphead, schlub (also shlub) [slang], schnook [slang], simpleton, stock, stupe, stupid, thickhead, turkey, woodenhead, yahoo, yo-yo".

  Saying someone is a dimwit (if there's their action supporting your comment) can be a fair criticism and could be acceptable for use in formal situations such as during a meeting; but you must then be careful that your comment is well deserved.

Something more complicated and vulgar, a personal attack and untrue:

- [excrement](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/excrement) noun
  ex·​cre·​ment | \ ˈek-skrə-mənt
  : waste matter discharged from the body

  You can say that "they are excrement" (or use the simpler four letter word), you can say that "their ideas are excrement", or you can say that "they have excrement for brains".

  The first example is unclear, inviting further discussion, allowing you to launch a [second punch](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+one-two+punch).

  The second example is to the point, but clearly an exaggeration.

  The third example is clearly an exaggeration and untrue, but what you mean is clear; to a native English speaker.

> Context: I need it in a dialog of the following form:
>
> A: How does <very simple/obvious thing> work?

1. B: It works like <explanation>, dimwit.
2. B: It works like <explanation>, sh*t for brains.

The first example has the advantage that you can substitute most of the synonyms in that list, mix it up, and leave third party listeners in suspense over what witty ([pithy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pithy)) insult you will dish out next; if others laugh or applaud that deepens the hurt of the insult.

It can horribly backfire ***if*** **you** are the one whom is wrong, or your usage is too strong for the situation; reserve the best insults for the truly worthy.

Comment: +1 "dolt" is one of my favorites for this purpose

Comment: +1 for "sh*t for brains".

Comment: @jxh I’d agree with your +1 if it weren’t for the fact that my dad keeps calling me that, so I’ve decided it’s a super-positive expression that means ‘awesome’.

Answer (score 4):

Going along with the “you can say absolutely anything as long as it’s in quotes” mantra:

> the stronger the insult the better

I’m not 100% versed of insults used by English-speaking countries other than the U.S., but the “stronger” titles for people who are a) incompetent, b) lacking knowledge, or c) ignorant oftentimes use the word “fuck” as an adverb (a word that should be avoided in most conversations due to its stigma), such as:

1) “idiot” -> “fucking idiot”

“Idiot” being a noun for somebody who is incompetent or not knowledgeable, as would “fool”

2) “retard” -> “fucking retard” -> “retarded fuck”

“retard” being a noun for somebody who is either physically or mentally handicapped, colloquially used as a euphemism for somebody who is remarkably a) unintelligent, b) incompetent, c) socially awkward.  The socially awkward description stems from the fact that there are types of mental disabilities that could make one not as socially capable as a person without said disability.

“retarded fuck” meaning the insulted is a “fuck”, which usually doesn’t mean much in and of itself, but detailed with “retarded”.  Keep in note that all of these are HIGHLY subjective, and insults are very dialectic.  However, if you come to California, this is what you’ll probably hear.

3) “dumbass” -> “fucking dumbass”

“dumbass” being a compounding of “dumb” (similar to foolish) and “ass”, a euphemism for one’s rear or a donkey that has been tacked into the expression for good measure.

4) “dumbfuck” -> NOT “fucking dumbfuck”

“dumbass” being very similar to “dumbass”, with “dumb” meaning foolish, and a curse added on to the end.  Do not use the adverb “fucking” before this word because it has already been added to the word itself.  I consider this word to be one of the most concise insults of this list, along with “idiot”.

While those are the “strong”est I could think of, I do caution you to only use these with very close friends who are 100% casual with cursing and insulting like this.  Misuse of a language is fast road to a hospital, and I implore you to use these with high discretion.

For things such as work encounters with coworkers, I would recommend some of the words you listed, such as “silly”:

A: How do put this square peg in the round hole?

B: You don’t put the square peg in the round hole, you put the round peg in the round hole and the square peg in the square hole, **you silly**.

Again, these expressions are highly dialectal, so you’ll hear different words or expressions in different cities and countries.

Comment: F**ktard is popular around these parts.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some great options if you want to steer clear of profanity:

*F**kwit* can be converted to **halfwit**

> A foolish or stupid person

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/halfwit)

*Dips**t* can be converted to **dimwit**

> A stupid or silly person.

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dimwit)

*dumbf**ck* can be converted to **dumbass** or **dumbarse**

> Stupid; brainless

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dumb-ass)

*Di**head* becomes **dolt** or **dunce**

*Dolt*:

> A stupid person

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dolt)

*Dunce*:

> A person who is slow at learning; a stupid person.

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dunce)

*Dips**t* can also become **dipstick**

> a stupid or inept person.

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dipstick)

**spastic** could be viable.

> Incompetent or uncoordinated.

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spastic)

Brits also have the option of **wanker**

> A contemptible person (used as a general term of abuse).

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wanker)

Answer (score 3):

In Britain we have the wonderful word [numpty](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/numpty) for which we are indebted to the Scots and which the Oxford Dictionary Online defines as

> A stupid or ineffectual person.

with examples

> ‘confused numpties who have little idea of what they're talking about’
>
> ‘what a complete numpty!’
>
> ‘Then a numpty, walkie-talkie jobsworth in a parka sidles up and tells me to shove off.’

The nice thing about 'numpty' is that it is an insult but is not, unless preceded by an obscenity, offensive to people other than the target. It can also be used to confess to stupidity on one's own part "I forgot my wedding anniversary. What a numpty I am!"; to  insult person you are talking to you "You double booked the Honeymoon Suite? You complete  numpty!"; and to insult a third person or a whole group of third parties "Trust the Government? I wouldn't trust that set of numpties to organise a booze-up in a brewery!"

Answer (score 2):

"Stupid git" is good choice, although that's British.

Stronger insults often include profanity.

Often stronger insults question a person's intelligence more than their knowledge, so moron, cretin, etc.

Ignoramus is a really good choice. It's strong, and implies ignorance, but as a permanent condition.

Answer (score 2):

Avoiding profanity, could use "Cretin".

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cretin

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to explicitly (and rudely) say "you know nothing" / "you are clueless".  Equally good is is an insulting way of saying "this is obvious".

> It works like <explanation>. **Duh**.

Definition ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/duh))

2. **—used derisively** to indicate that something just stated is all too obvious or self-evident

Many usage examples you'll find show a self-deprecating use (when you remember something you should have thought of earlier), or in response to something obvious said by someone else (as in MW's definition 2).

But it also works after stating something simple/basic/obvious that the other person apparently didn't know, as an insult.

Answer (score 1):

I tried putting ignorant into a thesaurus and found a large number of words quite quickly.

You might sort these for preference by, for example deciding if you prefer unaware (extremes chosen by me, obtuse, thick, dense, moronic, imbecilic, shallow-brained, cretinous) over untrained (examples include unlearned, untaught, uncultivated, unenlightened, , unread, unschooled, , uninformed, nescient, benighted, superficial, inerudite, know-nothing, destitute of knowledge,  lowbrow).

I personally prefer to use a word that I know (possibly newly discovered) that the other person might well misunderstand. So I'm offering a decision between whether you make yourself feel better at saying something and whether you really wish them to understand how know-nothing they are. Further, is this person exhibiting a lack of knowledge, or a lack of experience or, perhaps worst, an unwillingness to do any thinking at all, perhaps with no curiosity and an unwillingness to change?

In writing this I discover the word nescient (lacking knowledge, ignorant), new to me and perhaps appropriate for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

In more recent years, a newer term has come to be somewhat widely used, **headass.**

> A term used when one says something either obscured, unbelievable, or stupid

The insult is somewhat colloquial, but nonetheless passes the meaning on quite clearly and without ambiguity.

> How does this work?
>
> It works like this, you absolute **headass**

This can, as with most insults, be modified with the use of *f•••ing* or *imbecilic* for example.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the person's name.  If you are fortunate, their name is Jane.

In that case, the most compelling answer begins with ***"Jane, you ignorant slut..."***.

Please note that it does help if your name happens to be Dan, and you're performing on a Saturday Night Live skit.

Comment: Snort. Sadly this is getting to be an old, obscure reference...

Answer (score 0):

Fool.

> a jester or clown, especially one retained in a royal or noble household.